# Forbidden request status while using oxford dictionary API in javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I am learning to use web apis. I started with oxford dictionary api and read this [documentation](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation#!/Dictionary32entries/get_entries_source_lang_word_id). This is the code I have written so far.

```
const app_id = '8***c965';
const app_key = '395******162b317b9d6f3c6cd0b3930b';
const language = "en";
var word_id = 'oblivion';
var url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/' + language + '/' + word_id.toLowerCase();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('app_id', app_id); 
request.setRequestHeader('app_key', app_key);
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");

request.onload = function() {
    //Begin accessing JSON data here

    var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(data);
}

request.send();
```

This code returns status `403 Forbidden` in the console. According to the documentation, this should have worked. Can anybody shed some light about what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have exceeded a monthly limit. The limit is 3k per month.
You can see it in "statistic" tab on https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com.

For development it is better to use some mock server in order to save hits for real application.

Comment: I never received the results once. Also, I checked the statistics on the website for the last 12 months but it has 0 queries. Seems like this was not the problem.

Comment: Hmmm interesting...
1. Have you tried create another account?
2. Also when you are sign in on the website, when you open documentation https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation, a "try it" functionality sents your credential. What is happening in that case?
BTW, I have got 403 Forbidden because I exceeded limit.

Comment: Ok. I put your code to my browser, and I got the same error.
When I changed credential to my then I got "Access to fetch at 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/oblivion' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy", because Oxford Dictionary doesn't support CORS and you must use proxy according to post by jplew https://forum.oxforddictionaries.com/api/discussion/18/error-message-no-access-control-allow-origin-or-i-can-t-get-my-client-side-request-to-work#latest. I did proxy and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe it is stupid question, but did you write correctly your app_id and app_key? Without *** (stars) ? Did you generate credentials on your account?

Comment: Yes I double checked the credentials from my account.

Comment: Ok. I run your code on Chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 (Official Build) (64-bit). How do you run yours?

Comment: I used chrome's official build. Not working now on this project so don't remember the chrome version.

Comment: Please give me your email. I will send you my keys. I don't want paste it here. After receiving mail you can remove address from here.

Answer (score 0):

If none of what mentioned above fixed the issue this could be it.
Their API version 1 got shut down on 30 June 2019 and replaced by V2.

From their documentation:

> Users on a FREE account will need to update their plan to either
> Prototype or Developer to get access to v2. More information about our
> new plans is available here.
>
> Use 'v1' in the URL to request version 1, and 'v2' to request version
> 2.

Read about migration guide here: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/version2